# kivy unable to load image

Tags: python, kivy

Kivy is not loading an image for me, its showing '[image][error] error reading file x.png'

My python code (in short) is:

```py
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
from kivymd.uix.snackbar import Snackbar
import requests

class Home(FloatLayout):
    pass

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.theme_cls = ThemeManager()
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = ('LightBlue')
        Window.size = (400,600)
```

Kivy file (again part that matters) is:

```
MDBottomNavigation:
     MDBottomNavigationItem:
        text:'Home'
        name: 'Home'
        Home:

            Image:
                source:'khatam.png'

            Image:
                source: 'togeather.png'
```

I have pip installed Kivy with all its dependencies(including GStreamer) and have OpenCV. Also, I am using Pycharm. The rest of the code is working just fine only this part is bugged.

I am relatively new. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the `png` files in the same folder as your python code?